# Gguide to implement bonding/pairing in bleno (BLE)

Tags: node.js, bleno

Can anyone give a list of Instructions on how to implement Bonding/Pairing in BLENO? I have created a list of ble profiles but don't know what to code or do in order to implement pairing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bleno doesn't really support proper bonding. Use BlueZ instead.

Comment: How can I use BlueZ for my bleno JS code to implement pairing.? Please  explain